# subquery delete not working in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I have the following query which is joined and left joined:

```
   select aad.id
                  from [table1] aad
                  left outer join [table2] itm
                    on aad.table2_id = itm.id
                  left outer join [table3] eac
                    on aad.id = eac.table1_id
                  LEFT JOIN [table4] ces
                    ON eac.car_id = ces.id
                  LEFT join [table5] ci
                    on ces.car_information_id = ci.id
                 INNER join [table6] groupBi
                    on aad.capatibilty_degree_group_id = groupBi.id
                 where ces.id is null
                   and aad.depot_ammu_estimate = 123
```

The result of the above query is:

```
id
-----
2433
2431
```

Ids of [table1] table(aad.id) then I want to delete this records of that table then I query following syntax:

```
delete
  FROM [table1] w
 where w.id in (select aad.id
                  from [table1] aad
                  left outer join [table2] itm
                    on aad.table2_id = itm.id
                  left outer join [table3] eac
                    on aad.id = eac.table1_id
                  LEFT JOIN [table4] ces
                    ON eac.car_id = ces.id
                  LEFT join [table5] ci
                    on ces.car_information_id = ci.id
                 INNER join [table6] groupBi
                    on aad.capatibilty_degree_group_id = groupBi.id
                 where ces.id is null
                   and aad.depot_ammu_estimate = 123)
```

What is it happen, there are no records to delete. I don't know that what is happening that the above query does not delete the records.

Comment: Mayby You've already delete them, but did not commit/rollback changes?

Comment: No this record exists.i am not beginner

Comment: Should work fine. Like was commented, you're probably not checking the results correctly or not committing, etc.  If you want further help, please provide a minimal but complete script that we can use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: All these LEFT JOINs make little sense to me; you basically want an exists(). And the `LEFT JOIN ... where ces.id is null` can be rewitten into a not exists() And it appears you don't need the `LEFT join [table5] ci on ces.car_information_id = ci.id` term at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `ces.id is null` with `nvl(ces.id,0) = 0`

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is in using "is null" in query .i do not know why happen this problem

```
delete
  FROM [table1] w
 where w.id in (select aad.id
                  from [table1] aad
                  left outer join [table2] itm
                    on aad.table2_id = itm.id
                  left outer join [table3] eac
                    on aad.id = eac.table1_id
                  LEFT JOIN [table4] ces
                    ON eac.car_id = ces.id
                  LEFT join [table5] ci
                    on ces.car_information_id = ci.id
                 INNER join [table6] groupBi
                    on aad.capatibilty_degree_group_id = groupBi.id
                 where nvl(ces.id,0)=0 
                   and aad.depot_ammu_estimate = 123)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have testing env to work with syntax, but try EXIST clause. Something like this.

```
DELETE FROM [table1] t WHERE
EXISTS
(
  select 1
                  from [table1] aad
                  left outer join [table2] itm
                    on aad.table2_id = itm.id
                  left outer join [table3] eac
                    on aad.id = eac.table1_id
                  LEFT JOIN [table4] ces
                    ON eac.car_id = ces.id
                  LEFT join [table5] ci
                    on ces.car_information_id = ci.id
                 INNER join [table6] groupBi
                    on aad.capatibilty_degree_group_id = groupBi.id
                 where ces.id is null
                   and aad.depot_ammu_estimate = 123 
and aad.id=t.id;
)
```